# How to send a title in Forge 1.12.1

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

My current way of sending titles to the Player is by placing a redstone torch next to a command block (which contains the title commands), but even that does not work:

```
BlockPos blockPos = new BlockPos(675, 236, 457);
IBlockState iBlockState = world.getBlockState(blockPos);
Material material = iBlockState.getMaterial();

world.setBlockState(blockPos, Blocks.REDSTONE_TORCH.getDefaultState(), 1);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with forge but you have to send the packet `SPacketTitle` to the player. see [this](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/44257-1102-solved-sending-vanilla-title-packet-to-player/)

Comment: If you place the torch next to the command block manually (i.e. as a player) does that work? If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the redstone idea worked. I just called CommandSetBlock.execute(server, sender, args). I used my own string array in args <3